# VBA Macro : get the maximum match cell value to a group of criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have 4 group of criteria to match.
If a range data to check from sheet1.range("A1:J1") contain : 10 type of fruits.
I want to know which group has the maximum match with the range data.

For example :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jir9g.jpg)

I try the following code, which do not works:

```vb
Sub Get_the_relevant_group()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim searchList As Variant
    Dim searchVal As Variant, val2check As Variant
    Dim rng2check As Range
    Dim cell2check As Range
    Dim iMatch As Integer
    
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sh = wb.ActiveSheet
    
    iCol = sh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rng2check = sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 1), sh.Cells(1, iCol))
    

    GroupA = Array("Apple", "Banana", "Coconut", "Grape", "Orange", "Guava", "Durian", _
         "Blackcurrent", "Mango", "Strawberry")
    GroupB = Array("Apple", "Coconut", "Guava", "Mango", "Strawberry", "Lime", "Grape", "Pear", "Blueberry", "Lemon")
    GroupC = Array("Apple", "Grape", "Durian", "Pineapple", "Watermelon", "Blueberry", "Banana", "Lemon")
    GroupD = Array("Apple", "Orange", "Lime", "Plums", "Pear", "Lemon", "Coconut", "Grape")
        
    For iGroup = 1 To 4
        If iGroup = 1 Then searchList = GroupA
        If iGroup = 2 Then searchList = GroupB
        If iGroup = 3 Then searchList = GroupC
        If iGroup = 4 Then searchList = GroupD
        
        For Each cell2check In rng2check
            If cell2check <> "" Then
                For Each searchVal In searchList
                    val2check = cell2check.Value
                    If InStr(1, val2check, searchVal) > 0 Then
                        iMatch = iMatch + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next searchVal
             End If
            If iMatch = iCol Then Exit For
        Next cell2check
    Next iGroup
End Sub
```

I hope somebody can give me solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` to be forced to declare all variables (e.g. `Dim iCol As Long`,...). Add the line `iMatch = 0` right after `For iGroup = 1 To 4` and the line `Debug.Print "Group" & iGroup & " Total = " & iMatch` right after the line `Next cell2check`. Now you can see some results in the Immediate window (`Ctrl`+`G`). Please share what you expect the code to do e.g.: should it be a `Sub` and do something, should it be a `Function` and return something...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it (I've commented on the lines so you see what it's doing):

```
Sub Get_the_relevant_group()

Dim ws As Worksheet, SearchArr, SearchString As String, i As Long, j As Long
Dim iGroup, iMatch As Long, iCounter As Long, iCol As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

iCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'Below turns the search list into a 1d array
SearchArr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, iCol)).Value))
SearchString = Join(SearchArr, ",") 'Turn the 1d array into a string which can be searched using Instr

For i = 7 To 10 'Use row numbers the groups are on
    iGroup = Split(ws.Range("C" & i).Value, ",") 'Split the group into an array
    iMatch = 0 'Reset the counters
    iCounter = 0
    For j = LBound(iGroup) To UBound(iGroup) 'From start of array to end
        iGroup(j) = Replace(iGroup(j), " ", "") 'remove any spaces if it does
        If iGroup(j) <> "" Then 'Checks it is not blank
            iCounter = iCounter + 1
            If InStr(SearchString, iGroup(j)) > 0 Then 'See if current item is found in search string
                iMatch = iMatch + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next j
    ws.Range("J" & i).Value = iCounter 'Send results to the sheet for the group
    ws.Range("K" & i).Value = iMatch
Next i
    
End Sub
```

With the `For i = 7 To 10` you could of course find the last row if you had a lot more groups that would come in so that could be a variable instead.

Comment: Thank you.  It is almost completely solve my question but may be i don't describe it clearly.  I use my personal macro to check the other worksheet, so the result is no need to display  in the review sheet.  I only run from my personal macro include the group list and get the result in message box that this review sheet is related to the group B.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you're saying. I based it on the image you provided.

Comment: The other question  :  if i want to know  the column number of the second match cell value, do i  write :  if iCounter = 1 then matchVal1 = ws.Cells(1, iCounter) , if iCounter = 2 then matchval2 = ws.Cells(1, iCounter) etc. Do you have a best way?

Comment: I mean that the search range (ws.range("A1:J1")  is the other workbook for review.  I save the macro and  the group criteria in Personal.xls. but it's ok i will find the way to finished it. Thank you for your help.  Can you help me for other question in previous comment

Comment: It won't work because iCounter and iMatch are just counters, they don't return the column of the matching fruit. The easiest way to add onto my code would be to have an array that gets ReDimmed and expanded each time there is a match. So you would get MatchArray(1,1) = first match and MatchArray(2,1) = second match etc.

Comment: What are you wanting to do with that? Are you just wanting the column number or the value of the fruit that is matched? Because `iGroup(j)` will give you the name of the fruit.